# Logitech G602 League Of Legends Profile Not Setting

Tags: league-of-legends, technical-issues, mouse

I am having a strange problem with my Logitech G602. When I open up the game and actually play the game, my profiles and keys for the mouse will not be set unless I make League Of Legends the default profile, which I do not want to do. But the rest of my games (Starcraft 2, Dota 2, CSGO, etc.) all set and are detected by the mouse and work fine. What could be going on?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you actually set the **CLIENT** to use the profile, not the launcher. If you do not change anything, your keybindings should work in the launcher but not the game.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It seems that the file location for the client changes every update though, making the G602 forget where it is, and making it so the key binds on the mouse no longer work. Is there a permanent client location for LoL?

Comment: It shouldn't change, I'm not on my home PC right now, but it should be in the RADS or close to the RADS folder in League of Legends.

Comment: Yeah I was in the RADS folder and it seems each time, that folder gets a different name/number, making my mouse forget it. It did that on 6.15 and 6.14 as well :/

Comment: In that case, you're out of luck, save writing a macro for your macro.